# Inserting an element into a sorted list

Tags: java, android, arrays, logic, sorting

Ok I'm using getSharedPreferences to store my high score but before I fill it up I wanted to sort the scores into ascending order via and array, but if it finds a Score less than it in the first pos then it wont check the rest for the smallest?

```
    //function to add score to array and sort it
    public void addscoretoarray(int mScore){
    for(int pos = 0; pos< score.length; pos++){
        if(score[pos]  > mScore){
            //do nothing
        }else {
                //Add the score into that  position
                score[pos] = mScore;
                break;
            }
    }
    sortArray(score);
}
```

should I call sortArray() before and after the loop to fix this problem or is there a better method to achieve the same results?

I should also mention that the sortArray(score) function is just calling Arrays.sort(score)
where score is an array of mScore

EDIT:
based on what @Vincent Ramdhanie posted I have revised the post:

```
    public void addscoretoarray(int mScore){
    int pos = score.length; 
    //sort the array (in ascending order)
    sortArray(score);

    //go though the array( in descending order) and check for a place that suits the conditions
    while(pos>=0 && score[pos] > mScore){ 
         pos--; //do nothing as score[pos] is larger than mScore
    }
     //so once a pos is found (e.g. broke out of the while loop)
     //check that it is still in the list
    if(pos >= 0){
        //if it is then move everything down 1 position
        for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++){
            score[i] = score[i+1];
        }
        //replace the initial pos with the new score
        score[pos] = mScore;
    }
}
```

I still believe that it will drop off the list when in the `for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++){` loop.

Comment: Due to break statement you are exiting the for loop .

Comment: call `sortArray()` **before** comparisons start, and after that, you check with the largest entry, and move backwards.

Comment: thank you Cthulhu but I'm now wondering, it is going to replace the smallest one as it will be the first one it will reach but there may be more than one score smaller than it, how would i replace the highest of the scores smaller than it?

Comment: @RussellCargill Once you sort, you'll know that the ones to the left of that index are smaller. I don't see the issue, I'm sorry.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest! haha

I want to sort my high score array and add high scores to it and replace the most relevent ones and bump down the rest

Comment: @Cthulhu thank you anyway, I think I might rethink the logic behind what I want to do before I ask any more about this

Comment: Ahh, you are looking to **insert** an element at the right spot, while keeping array-length constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not keep the array of scores sorted. So your add score to array will assume that the array is sorted in descending order all the time. The new score to be inserted will simply push the lowest score off the array as it is inserted. You can then use an insert algorithm something like this:

```
   insertScore(int[] scores, int mscore){
        //find insert point
        int i = 0;
        while(i < scores.length && scores[i] > mscore){
            i++;
        }
        if(i < scores.length){
            //you found a place to insert the score
            for(int j = scores.length-1; j > i; j--){
                scores[j] = scores[j - 1];
            }
            scores[i] = mscore;
        }
   }
```

In this case there is no need to resort the array.

Answer (score 5):

If I understood your correctly then I suggest this

```
    int[] a1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 };
    int mScore = 5;

    int[] a2 = new int[a1.length + 1];
    Arrays.sort(a1);
    int p = Arrays.binarySearch(a1, mScore);
    if (p < 0) {
        p = -p - 1;
        System.arraycopy(a1, 0, a2, 0, p);
        System.arraycopy(a1, p, a2, p + 1, a1.length - p);
        a2[p] = mScore;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a2));
```

output

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Note that it inserts only unique values

Answer (score 2):

See [javadoc to @return  of binarySearch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T)):

> Returns the index of the search key, if it is contained in the list; **otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the list: the index of the first element greater than the key, or list.size() if all elements in the list are less than the specified key**. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addscoretoarray(int mScore){
    for(int pos = 0; pos< score.length; pos++){
        if(score[pos]  > mScore){
            //do nothing
        }else {
                //Add the score into that  position
                score[pos] = mScore;
                break;
            }
    }
    sortArray(score);
}
```

there are some major bugs in the code.

1. `score[pos] = mScore;`
   in this statement, you are assigning `mScore` at position `pos` which will result in the value stored at `pos` being lost.
2. If you are using an array, then to store any element in between, you need to move all the remaining elements 1 position to the right, which you are not doing here.
3. `score[pos] = mScore;
           break;`

the break will break the loop in the first iteration itself, after storing the element at pos.

Suggestion :

Use arraylist instead of native array.
Modified pseudo code:

```
public void addscoretoarray(int mScore){
    int index = getFirstIndexOfScoreGreaterThanmScore(); // need to implement it
    if(index == -1){ // no element greater than mscore
    score.add(mScore);
    }else{
    score.add(index,mScore);
}
//   sortArray(score); // no need to call this if the list is initially empty as the insertion will be in sorted order itself
if(score.length == maxSize){
//do whateverwhen the list is full as per your requirements
}
}
```