# How to keep track of an array element after sorting in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array of integers, which has to be kept sorted. Therefore, after every element insertion, i call `Arrays.sort()`. In addition, I have to keep track of the last element inserted, so that I can reach it after sorting with an `O(1)` complexity.
For example, consider the following scenario:

```
int[] array = new int[10];
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
array[2] = 3;
array[3] = 8;
array[4] = 5;
int indexAfterSort = sort(array, 4);
```

`indexAfterSort` would now contain `3`.
The `int sort(int[] array, int elementIndexToTrack)` method gets the array, and an `int` which is the index of the element to track. It returns the index of this element after the sort is complete.
I am looking for an efficient way to achieve this, without adding to the `O(nlogn)` complexity of the sorting algorithm, usually performed by `Arrays.sort()`. Therefore I want to avoid searching for the element after sorting, with binary search for example. My last resort would be to copy the `Array.sort()` algorithm and implement the changes I need there, but there might be an easier solution.

Comment: Have you considered using a heap, rather than sorting every time?

Comment: @fabian Worst case for binary search is O(log n), O(n) would be for inserting into the array.

Comment: If these are just integers, you could use `Arrays.sort(arr)` then `Arrays.binarySearch(arr, num)`

Edit: What do you mean by "without adding to O(nlogn) complexity? A binary search is O(logn), and O(nlogn)+O(logn)=O(nlogn)

Comment: @IsmailBadawi I have considered `TreeSet` and `PriorityQueue`, but they don't support an _index_ notion, therefore I wanted to simplify the issue and use an array instead.

Comment: @KevinL you are right, but it's still more efficient to avoid a binary search, and just get the new index with O(1).

Comment: Why not avoid sorting by [Inserting an element into a sorted list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13776697/2188186)? Then you can easily keep track of the last element.

Comment: What do you mean by get the new index with O(1)?

Comment: @KevinL, if he insert the element into a sorted list and store the index of where it was stored. He would get it in O(1), but it is impossible if he keeps sorting every time.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun How is that O(1) time? You need at least O(n) to insert into a sorted list, even if you only do it once

Comment: @KevinL, from what I understood he wants to retrieve it at a later time at O(1) *as he doesn't mind sorting which is worse than O(n)*.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun but method stores the index means the index can be retrieved later in O(1)...

Answer (score 0):

Keeping these numbers in a sorted array will be very inefficient. Whenever you insert a new integer in the right place, you will need to move all of the array that has a higher value, making insertion very inefficient. Use a different structure.

Whatever structure you choose, keeping track of the last item inserted is easy. Create a variable

```
int lastItemInserted
```

and every time you insert something, write to it.

Comment: i have to keep track of the **index** of the new element, not the element's value.

Comment: Then use a variable 'indexOfLastItemInserted' and write the index to that.

Comment: only lists and arrays support indices, i cannot use a heap or a tree